# Length of modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

Let $M, N$ be two $A$-modules. If there is a surjective $A$-map from $M$ to $N$, can we conculde that $\ell(M) \geq \ell(N)$. Here $\ell(M)$ is the number of modules in a composition series of $M$. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes. Given a composition series of $N$, pulling back gives a series (that has simple consecutive quotient) of the same length. This series in $M$ may not be maximal, hence the length is $\leq \ell (M)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f: M \to N$ is a surjection, then $M/\ker{f} \cong N$. If $M$ has finite length, then

$$\ell(M) = \ell(\ker{f}) + \ell(M/\ker{f}) = \ell(\ker{f}) + \ell(N),$$

so $\ell(M) \geq \ell(N)$.